# Matlab – image transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y7d5.png)
Hi everyone, I'm still wondering what the parameters in the matrix can mean. Could someone help me, I couldn't find any video that explains it properly to me.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix represents an [Affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) which can be used to e.g. translate or rotate an image.